# Access licensed files only after admin changes order status to completed

Tags: commerce

I watched the [Commerce File screencast](http://commerceguys.com/blog/commerce-module-tuesday-commerce-file-screencast) which shows how to create a downloadable file as a product. It appears to be for version 7.x-1.x but currently the recommended version is 7.x-2.x which has since changed significantly.

I'm trying to achieve the same outcome as the screencast whereby the user can only see his licensed files after the order has been changed to completed by an admin. Currently, the moment the user submits his order, he can already see his files. I tried checking the checkout rules, however, the only event option closest to what I want to achieve is "After updating an existing commerce order", and that did not work either.

How can I prevent users from accessing the licensed file until the order has been processed?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have time to watch the screencast.

You could create two rules, the first which trigger when an order is payed in full, this rule could change the order status to pending.

Then you could make another rule which triggers when an order is saved, with the condition that it is in the pending state, it is changed to completed (which allows access to the files).

This could cause complications if you actually use the 'pending' order status for other workflows, in which case you might need to make a custom status you can use as an in between for your review process (using this module https://drupal.org/project/commerce_custom_order_status).

Comment: Yes, I see your point. However, my downloadable file is supposed to be a free download, but I would still want the workflow to proceed as per the screencast, whereby the admin reviews the order before allowing users access to the download. Is this use case even possible?